# Wishing luck to third person

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

I want to express to an uninvolved person that I wish luck for some people involved in an endeavor.

> I'm keen interested to watch the result and wish lucky for that.

`Wish lucky for that` **or** `I do wish them best of luck`

Comment: It's a little difficult to get what you're trying to convey here.

Comment: Synxmax, why do you think lucky could be the correct word?

Comment: *To wish someone luck* is perfectly grammatical.

Comment: Also note you would say "I am keenly interested", not "I am keen interested". "Keen" is an adjective and so must modify a noun, while "keenly" is an adverb and so modifies a verb or an adjective. Here you are modifying "interested", which is an adjective, so you need an adverb. An alternative way to express the idea would be to say, "My interest is keen" or "I have a keen interest in this subject".

Comment: I have the impression part of the reason this question was closed is simply because OP isn't a fluent native speaker. I'm not convinced Jim's edit of the wording helped much either, since it discarded the crucial information that OP himself works with the team he hopes will do well. IMHO the question was unnecessarily and peremptorily closed, and at the very least OP should have been given a day or so to clarify exactly what sentiment he wished to convey, in what context.

Answer (score 1):

You could say *I wish them luck on this project*, or if you addressing them directly you could say *I wish you luck on this project*, or maybe *I wish you and your team luck on this project* if you are just addressing one member of the team. If you want to be less formal, or you want to say it shorter, you could say *Good luck, guys!*.

Comment: Which one is more correct , `I do wish them best of luck` or the one you mentioned `I wish them luck on this project`

Comment: I don't think you need the word *do* in there. I'm pretty sure it's technically correct, but I don't hear many people speak like that. It would then be *I wish them luck on this project*.

Comment: *I do wish them* has stress on *do*; it is good to use it when you *do* want to emphasize a point.

Answer (score 0):

Saying "Good luck!" to *someone else* is largely just a set phrase anyway, and since OP says he's actually *working with the team* it doesn't really seem appropriate to say to someone else that he wishes them luck with the project. Apart from anything else, the team should be expecting the project to succeed because they do a good job, not because they're "lucky".

I suggest that if OP wishes to report his attitude towards the team/project to a third party, he should probably say something like...

> I [really] hope the project is successful.

...which could equally well apply if OP himself has no actual involvement with the project, or perhaps something like...

> I really hope we we can do a good job on this project.

...if he personally is an active member of the team. There are plenty of alternatives, obviously. I myself would be likely to say *I'm thoroughly committed to the success of this project*.